# make the bundle available on any host (0.0.0.0)

Tags: express, webpack, lan

## I am trying to access `localhost` in my android phone.

### I am using [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) with an `express` server.

I do know how to set the host in [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost) though. 
But I don't see any options to specify a host of `0.0.0.0` in [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware).

*Hope that my problem is clear enough*

Answer (score 1):

```
app.listen(3001, 'localhost', function() {
  console.log("... port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

This the way you specify port and host . If you don't specify localhost then it's default exposed in 0.0.0.0

So below code listens in 0.0.0.0

```
app.listen(3001,  function() {
  console.log("... port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

**Update:**

You can set your ip address directly in webpack config file:

```
devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',//your ip address
    port: 8080,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not have any problem accessing my `express server`. It works fine.
The problem is, my assets (js, css and images) are being bundled via `webpack-dev-middleware`. And these assets are not being exposed to external device.

Comment: @RahulDahal did you try updating the webpack config file ?

Comment: i added taht to the answer

Comment: could you more details like how you are starting the server , how you are trying to access and t=other details if this is not working